# How to overcome honeypot listing on listing website? (Scrapy)

Tags: python, css, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm quite new to scrapy and looking to scrape a website with Scrapy for my research project.

The website in question has a number of classified listings on each page and on each page there is a honeypot listing that does not show when viewing from the browser (div with HappySpinoffs class in the code below), but when one inspects the DOM the listing is there but just hidden with CSS properties in a CSS block in the HTML (not in-line). I've inspected the HTML and there is no difference between the honeypot listing and the other listings on the page - the only difference being the CSS properties right above it in the HTML document. When I scrape the pages with Scrapy the Xpath selectors pick up on the honeypot listing and the bot gets blocked. The class names are dynamically generated and the position of the honeypot listing changes on each page. Looking at the CSS code-block below, only the honeypot listing's class is used - the others are just to throw one off.

I'm currently getting the listings through the following xpath `'/div[contains(@class, "js_resultTile")'` but then it catches the honeypot listing. I don't know how to grab all those css classes via xpath and check those to the listings I get so that the honeypot listing isn't scraped. Given that there is roughly 500,000 listings and that these need to be updated weekly, the solution must be super quick.

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="js_listingResultsContainer">
    <div class="b34_promotedTile js_resultTile js_pseudoLinkContainer js_rollover_container HappyReacting" data-listing-number="P108146928">...</div>
    <div class="b34_promotedTile js_resultTile js_pseudoLinkContainer js_rollover_container HappyMorrow" data-listing-number="P108079642">...</div>
    <div class="b34_promotedTile js_resultTile js_pseudoLinkContainer js_rollover_container HappyPumping" data-listing-number="P107587584">...</div>
    <div class="b34_promotedTile js_resultTile js_pseudoLinkContainer js_rollover_container HappyBudgeted" data-listing-number="P108129532">...</div>
    <div class="b34_promotedTile js_resultTile js_pseudoLinkContainer js_rollover_container HappyDormant" data-listing-number="P107692442">...</div>
    <div class="HappyMistimed js_resultTile" data-listing-number="106933717">...</div>
    <div class="HappySalivas js_resultTile" data-listing-number="108171874">...</div>
    <div class="HappyInanity js_resultTile" data-listing-number="108168952">...</div>
    <div class="HappyMiss js_resultTile" data-listing-number="108168914">...</div>
    <div class="HappyRevolver js_resultTile" data-listing-number="108138404">...</div>
    <div class="HappyMongrel js_groupedResultTile" data-listing-number="108165172">...</div>
    <div class="HappyMexicans js_groupedResultTile" data-listing-number="108111893">...</div>
    <div class="HappyScaling js_resultTile" data-listing-number="108131862">...</div>
    <div class="HappyJacob js_resultTile" data-listing-number="108108694">...</div>
    <div class="HappyWhelp js_resultTile" data-listing-number="108152564">...</div>
    <div class="HappyCome js_resultTile" data-listing-number="108163034">...</div>
    <div class="HappyBrawler js_resultTile" data-listing-number="108153616">...</div>
    <div class="HappySpinoffs js_resultTile" data-listing-number="107969187">...</div>
    <div class="HappyDrug js_resultTile" data-listing-number="108117622">...</div>
    <div class="HappyBecalmed js_resultTile" data-listing-number="108146204">...</div>
    <div class="HappyInfante js_resultTile" data-listing-number="108134673">...</div>
</div>
```

The CSS properties further up in the HTML of the page (not external CSS file):

```
   <style type="text/css">

                .HappySpinoffs
                {

                            position: absolute;
                        left: -6541px;

                }


                .HappyDefying
                {

                            position: absolute;
                        left: -9018px;

                }


                .HappyBenefit
                {

                            position: absolute;
                        left: -6421px;

                }


                .HappyAssert
                {

                            left: -7575px;
                        position: absolute;

                }


                .HappyForswore
                {

                            position: absolute;
                        left: -7694px;

                }


                .HappySmiler
                {

                            left: -5308px;
                        position: absolute;

                }

        </style>
}
```

Comment: Happy to clarify on any aspect of the post above if need be. Thank you for the help

Comment: Could you please (1) change the question title to have a _question_ format, and (2) at the beginning of your description, ask what you need before going into details? thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the help James. My first time posting...

Comment: Hi Azim. Sorry for that - it is my first post on stackoverflow. Have updated it to be a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude some `div`s by `class`:

```
'/div[contains(@class, "js_resultTile")][not(contains(@class, "js_pseudoLinkContainer"))]'
```

***UPDATE***
Then you need to parse honeypot's CSS first:

```
honeypots = response.xpath('//style[@some_selectors_here]/text()').re(r'\.(\S+)\s+\{')
```

Next you need to get `class` for each `div` you have:

```
for listing_div in response.xpath('//div[@class="js_listingResultsContainer"]/div'):
    div_class = listing_div.xpath('./@class').re_first(r'(\S+)$')
    if div_class not in honeypots:
        # process a link here
```

Comment: Hi gangabass. Thank you for the comment. The xpath selector /div[contains(@class, "js_resultTile works fine to select listings. What I'm looking to exclude from the scrapy requests is the honeypot listing (in this case HappySpinoffs but the class names are dynamically generated and change with each refresh). This requires that I parse the CSS above to identify the honeypot listing. All the other listings including the top ones are to be scraped hence why I used the /div[contains(@class, "js_resultTile Xpath selector.

Comment: @HeyThereWorld Still, you should be able to modify the code from this response to ignore the desired class.

Comment: Hey Galleacio, This is not possible as the honepot listing I have to identify with the above css classes changes name with each page refresh. The honeypot listing in the example above had a class of HappySpinoffs which was referenced in the css above but the name changes with each page reference so one can't just exclude it by using the code above. The above code from gangabass doesn't solve the problem in that he is trying to exclude the listings with class js_pseudoLinkContainer but those listings are valid listings.

Comment: Thank you Gangabass. This is great and I appreciate your help!!!